# Passing list values to t4 template

Tags: c#, t4

I have used the codes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586944.aspx) to pass parameters to a template file.

```
List<string> TopicList = new List<string>();
TopicList.Add("one");
TopicList.Add("two");
TopicList.Add("three");
TopicList.Add("four");
TopicList.Add("five");
PreTextTemplate1 t = new PreTextTemplate1();
t.Session = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TextTemplatingSession();
t.Session["TimesToRepeat"] = 5;
foreach (string s in TopicList)
{
    t.Session["Name"] = s;
}
t.Initialize();
string resultText = t.TransformText();
```

But everytime, all I get is the last value("five") in the Topic list.

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.Int32" name="TimesToRepeat" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="Name" #>

<# for (int i = 0; i < TimesToRepeat; i++) { #>
Line <#= Name #>
<# } #>

Actual Output:Line five
              Line five
              Line five
              Line five
              Line five

Expected Output: Line one
                 Line two
                 Line three
                 Line four
                 Line five
```

How can I make it such that I am able to generate every value in the Topic list in the template? 
Like the Expected Output.

Sorry for the lousy english and format of this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've not used TextTemplating, so let me preface that I may be incorrect here. As far as what I see by eyeballing it though, you are defining Name incorrectly in your template. Try the following:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.Int32" name="TimesToRepeat" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>" name="Names" #>

<# for (int i = 0; i < TimesToRepeat; i++) { #>
Line <#= Names[i] #>
<# } #>
```

You could also remove the TimesToRepeat and do a foreach instead:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>" name="Names" #>

<# foreach (string name in Names) { #>
Line <#= name #>
<# } #>
```

Comment: Ahh.. yes.. thats it! I was feeling that im close to figuring it out. Thanks alot!